# Trouble implementing error wrapper in Firestore callbacks

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following error wrapper in my application -

```kotlin
open class ResponseHandler {
    fun <T : Any> handleSuccess(data: T): Resource<T> {
        return Resource.success(data)
    }

    fun <T : Any> handleException(e: Exception): Resource<T> {
        return when (e) {
            is HttpException -> Resource.error(getErrorMessage(e.code()), null)
            else -> Resource.error(getErrorMessage(Int.MAX_VALUE), null)
        }
    }

    private fun getErrorMessage(code: Int): String {
        return when (code) {
            401 -> ERROR401
            404 -> ERROR404
            else -> GENERAL_ERROR
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper class that enables error / loading / success handling.
     */
    data class Resource<out T>(val status: Status, val data: T?, val message: String?) {
        companion object {
            fun <T> success(data: T?): Resource<T> {
                return Resource(Status.SUCCESS, data, null)
            }

            fun <T> error(message: String, data: T?): Resource<T> {
                return Resource(Status.ERROR, data, message)
            }

            fun <T> loading(data: T?): Resource<T> {
                return Resource(Status.LOADING, data, null)
            }
        }

        enum class Status {
            SUCCESS,
            ERROR,
            LOADING
        }
    }
}
```

and when using Retrofit + Coroutines, the use it quite straight forward -

```kotlin
suspend fun getSomethingFromPath(): ResponseHandler.Resource<Any> {
        return try {
            responseHandler.handleSuccess(networkApi.getSomethingFromPath())
        } catch (e : Exception) {
            responseHandler.handleException(e)
        }
    }
```

But when I want to get data from my Firestore collection, I am having trouble implementing the method  -

```kotlin
fun getAllApplicationActivities(groupsList: List<String>): ResponseHandler.Resource<ActivityCollectionModel> {
        Firebase.firestore.collection(ACTIVITIES_COLLECTION)
            .whereIn(GROUP_ID, groupsList)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                val activitiesList = documents.toObjects(ActivityCollectionModel::class.java)
                //Now what? 
            }
            .addOnSuccessListener { exception ->

            }
    }
```

How can I make the function return a `ResponseHandler.Resource<ActivityCollectionModel>` from the `addOnSuccessListener` and `addOnSuccessListener` callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) or suspendCancellableCoroutine

```
suspend fun getAllApplicationActivities(groupsList: List<String>) = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    Firebase.firestore.collection(ACTIVITIES_COLLECTION)
        .whereIn(GROUP_ID, groupsList)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            val activitiesList = documents.toObjects(ActivityCollectionModel::class.java)
            cont.resume(activitiesList)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            cont.resumeWithException(exception)
        }
}
```